# Compiling .rc file inline

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

I'm using Delphi XE4, and trying to achieve 32/64-bit compatibility, for this I need to store 2 DLLs (one 32 another 64) on resource, export them, and if the executable detects a 64 bit OS, it will use the 64 bit DLL. But I want to include this resource, only when compiling a 32bit version of the executable, so I'm trying to get something like this:

```
{$IFDEF WIN32}
{$R Resources.res Resources.rc}
{$ENDIF}
```

I don't know if it is right, because I couldn't test, the line: 
{$R Resources.res Resources.rc} doesn't works as I expected.

If I remove the Resources.res file it gives me error

[dcc32 Error] E1026 File not found: 'Resources.res'

If I leave a pre-compiled .res file, it doesn't refresh when building/compiling, even if I change my .rc file (removing one of the DLLs for example), the exe still getting the same size, so I believe it didn't refreshed the .res file...

My .rc file is:

```
X86RES RCDATA x86.dll
X64RES RCDATA x64.dll
```

How to get this rc file, compiled into resources, only when compiling for 32-bit environment?

Comment: I believe you're looking for `WIN32` and `WIN64`. You'll have to separate your scripts as well - one for 32 and the other for 64.

Comment: What script you mean?

Comment: I mean the `.rc` script file should be 2 files - and then use `WIN32` and `WIN64` to conditionally include one or the other.

Comment: Are you going to load the DLLs into the process that extracts them? In that case you can expect anti-malware software to take a dim view of your actions.

Comment: @JerryDodge I don't think that's really necessary because I will not load the DLLs inside my current process. Anyway, that's another problem...

Comment: @DavidHeffernan no, I'm not planning to load the DLLs in the process that extracts, any problem with anti-malware can be solved... The plan is to make this work first, then I take care about other details...

Comment: Looks like the solution is: when compiling to 64-bit, remove all lines from the RC file, and put them back when compiling for 32-bit...

Comment: No, the solution is exactly what I said. For a 32bit EXE, you need to include x86.dll, and for a 64bit EXE, you need to include x64.dll. This requires separation all the way down to the `.rc` file inclusion. The way you're proposing, a 32bit EXE will have both DLL's and a 64bit EXE will have neither. Unless that's what you want, in which case that's not clear in your question.

Comment: I think can be easier to: 3 resources (x86.dll, x64.dll, x64.exe), extract all, if OS 64-bits, run the x64.exe that loads the x64.dll... I think this can work, right? But doesn't change the main question.

Comment: Don't know if this matters here, but IIRC the {$R xxx.res xxx.rc } scheme only works inside the project file (dpr or dpk).

Comment: It matters, and I noted that right now, but on DPR files, I can't use {$IFDEF WIN32}, because doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

- Create two .rc files. One for the 32 bit DLL, and one for the 64 bit DLL.
- Compile both resource files to .res files.
- For the 32 bit build, link just the .res file containing the 32 bit DLL.
- For the 64 bit build, link both .res files.

Personally I'm not really much of a fan of getting the IDE/compiler to compile my resources. I like to do that in a pre-build script. But that's is mostly just personal taste.

It's worth pointing out the IDE/compiler will not re-compile the resource script when you compile the project. Only if you do a build, or delete the compiled .res file, will the resource script be re-compiled.

This is one of the reasons why I like to take charge of compiling resources. Another being that I get to choose the resource compiler that is used which can be important in scenarios where the Embarcadero resource compiler is deficient.

---

Judging by the comments, you have a more complex scenario that I describe above. However, the basics remain the same. You gain flexibility by having a one-to-one association between resource file and executable module. That flexibility allows you to link exactly the modules that you wish, and no more.

Comment: Just some questions:
How I'll link for the 32 bit build one .res, and for the 64-bit build another .res? I mean, automatically. And how can I compile both .res automatically too? And if I'm planning to have only one final exe (32bit) that should export the 64bit exe and both dlls, how all this would work?

Comment: I think is very much easier to work with one exe (32bit), and one .rc file, with 3 resources inside (32dll, 64dll, 64exe), so I compile all them to .res and extract them, if the 32bit exe detects a 64bit OS, run the 64bit.exe that loads the 64bit.dll... All this inside the same exe and same rc file. The only problem is that is senseless to have this rc file linked inside the 64bit version too, that's the entire problem, I could remove / add it manually, but can't the IDE handle this?

Comment: It seems to me like you've already decided on the solution. In which case I'm not sure why you are asking for advice. You want to know how to put different things in different executables. I give you a way to do it. You reject that and say that you'd rather put them all in, but then remove some of them later. Well, I wouldn't do it that way, but it's your choice.

Comment: FWIW, I don't see how embedding executables within other executables achieves 32/64 bit compatibility.

Comment: On the solution you gave me, I need 2 exes, for 32/64, right? But let's start from the point that maybe the person who will open the exe, don't know about 32/64 bit differences... So I need to deliver only one 32-bit (which run on all machines), and this one, run the 64 bit if necessary... But to work this way, looks like only removing the rc file from the project when compiling the 64bit version, and adding when compiling the 32-bit version...

Comment: Why are you determined to remove resources? What's wrong with adding the ones you need. Add what you need to the 64 bit version. So, just 64 bit modules. Then when you build the 32 bit executable, add whatever that needs. It's own 32 bit DLL, and the 64 bit executable.

Comment: Yes, it's ok... I think I'm missing something else because the solution proposed doesn't seem to make the job of manage all this resources easily... Thank you!

Comment: I think that the fundamental problem is your attempt to stuff all these executables into a single file. That's what is making life hard for you. Distribute the various modules separately and it's a piece of cake.

Comment: @user3810691 wouldn't it be easier if you do as David suggests (create two modules, one x86 and one x64) and then create a x86 installer that will deploy x64 or x86 files based on the OS? Looks like a cleaner approach.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan *It's worth pointing out the IDE/compiler will not re-compile the resource script when you compile the project. Only if you do a build, or delete the compiled .res file, will the resource script be re-compiled. This is one of the reasons why I like to take charge of compiling resources.* This is very true, but isn't the same true for your pre-build step calling the non-inline compiler? The only thing I'm seeing as an advantage for doing it in the pre-build step is you avoid the problems in some versions of Delphi where the compiler will sometimes claim File Not Found.

Comment: @jep No, the pre-build step is performed for every compile

Comment: Ah, now I went back and re-read something you said earlier that if the .res file was deleted it would be rebuilt. That's probably why me post-build step that deletes the .res file isn't causing a problem.